# Same mean, different variance - test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, variance, experiment-design

I have conducted an experiment where I am interested in how well different models for directional hearing works. For each model a sound is presented to a test subject, and the test subject expresses its perceived direction of the sound. The angle deviation from the presented sound is my data, and it can be both positive and negative depending on if it is to the right or to the left of the sound. All the test subjects are tested for all the models.

I am therefore expecting a mean of 0 degrees for all the models tested, but with different variances. A small variance should indicate a good model. Is there a statistical test for my needs? My supervisor suggests to use ANOVA, where I think Repeated Measures ANOVA should be used. However, as my understanding of ANOVA is so far, ANOVA compares the means of the different groups, while I am interested in the difference in variance.

Help is much appreciated! Please tell me if I have expressed myself unclear, and I will try to elaborate.

Comment: I will let someone who has experience of angular data answer your substantive question but on the face of it you are right and your supervisor is wrong.as ANOVA would compare the means between groups.